# Redis stops working and becomes unresponsive

Tags: redis

I have an application using Redis as a cache.

I have sporadic episodes where Redis suddenly becomes unresponsive. Even a simple curl test fails:

```
~ curl localhost:6379
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 6379: Connection refused
```

Redis console logs show no errors,

I am using this metrics exporter: https://github.com/oliver006/redis_exporter

During these episodes, `redis_up` is `0` and `redis_exporter_last_scrape_error` is `1` with no error detail.

FYI, I have 46 million short keys in Redis with empty string values.

How do I go about diagnosing and hopefully resolving this?

Comment: why on earth are you connecting to redis with curl? it's not a web server. connect with redis-cli and see for yourself. connection refused probably means you have too many open connections.

Comment: My production app doesn't use curl. I'm merely using curl as a diagnostic test to see if Redis is accepting TCP connections.

Comment: connect with redis-cli before this happens, and when this happens run INFO in an already connected redis-cli and see what's up. also look at the redis log. Sounds like you're overflowing your connection limit.